# Flutter add container below gridview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a container below a gridview in Flutter but it doesn’t work.

Here is my code:

```
class ThirdTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final title = "Store";

return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(title),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    body: new GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
      childAspectRatio: 2.1,
      children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index]),
          );
       }
      )
    ),
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    )
);
  }
}
```

I get two errors:

1. Too many positional arguments 0 expected but 1 found
2. Positional arguments must occur before named arguments

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Column widget

```
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      GridView(),
      Container(),
    ]
)
```